# Parent value of conditional initial tag - Docusign REST API

Tags: docusignapi

We are using the Docusign REST API. Now we have an conditional initial tab whose parent tag is a check box. I was able to set the check box to selected when there is no conditional initial field depending on it using the following code: checkboxTabs {tabLabel: "", selected: true}

But when I added the initial field and set the check box as its parent, I was not able to set the check box value.

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: can you share the code?

Comment: checkboxTabs {tabLabel: "CHECKBOX_LABEL_NAME", selected: true}

Comment: Were you able to get this to work based on the answer below?  If so can you accept as solution please?  -Ergin

Answer (score 0):

I see in the REST API guide it state this about Check Box tabs:

```
If the parent tab is a Checkbox, Radio button, Optional Signature, or Optional Initial use “on” as the value to show that the parent tab is active.
```

Are you doing this?

[DocuSign Documentation Page](http://www.docusign.com/developer-center/documentation)

Answer (score 0):

Docusign marks TabLabel for parent fields with some kind of GUID. Unfortunately, it is not visible in template editor, so you have to download template's xml and find your tab there.

Tab label will look like:

`<TabLabel>##parent3deb3045-7e98-4ae6-9186-1f9192e3cc79##LABEL_NAME</TabLabel>`

You have to use this name in order to prepopulate it.

P.S. This issue was very confusing. I think it should be mentioned in official documentation.